# Start activity after tabbar creation

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have created a tabbar at the bottom of every activity and I have it as my root activity now. I would like it to run the home screen first every time and still have my tab bar on the all the other activities. **The home screen is not in my tab bar**

The code here goes to Help instead of HomeScreen:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost;  

public class TabController extends TabActivity {  
/** Called when the activity is first created. */  
@Override  
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
    Intent intent;  

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Help.class);  
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Help").setIndicator("Help")  
                  .setContent(intent);  
    tabHost.addTab(spec);  

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Service.class);  
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Service").setIndicator("Service")  
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Inbox.class);  
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Inbox").setIndicator("Inbox")  
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, About.class);  
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("About").setIndicator("About")  
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, More.class);  
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("More").setIndicator("More")  
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

        //  Start home screen
  }
}
```

I have tried to just do a simple intent but that doesn't display my tab bar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made HomeScreen my first screen and ran this inside of the `Help.class`

```
startActivity(new Intent(presentActivity.this, NextActivity.class));
```